# Unable to log "Error" messages by Serilog's Application Insights sink

Tags: azure-application-insights, serilog

The following code snippet shows how Serilog's Application Insights sink is configured in our asp.net core 3.1 project. Due to some reasons, we do not want this particular sink to be configured **fully** by appsettings.json file:

```
public static IWebHostBuilder UseLogger(this IWebHostBuilder webHostBuilder)
        {
            webHostBuilder.ConfigureLogging(loggingBuilder => loggingBuilder.Services.AddSingleton<ILoggerProvider, DefaultLoggerProvider>());
            webHostBuilder.UseSerilog((hostingContext, loggerConfiguration) =>
            {
                loggerConfiguration
                    .ReadFrom.Configuration(hostingContext.Configuration)
                    .WriteTo.ApplicationInsights(new TelemetryConfiguration()
                    {
                        InstrumentationKey = "abcde-1234",
                        TelemetryChannel = new ServerTelemetryChannel()
                    },
                    new MyCustomTraceTelemetryConverter());
            });
            return webHostBuilder;
        }
```

Also, we have another version of the same extension method above per the following code snippet which is meant to support Azure Functions v3.0:

```
public static IFunctionsHostBuilder UseLogger(this IFunctionsHostBuilder builder, IConfiguration configuration)
        {   
            var loggerConfiguration = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
                .WriteTo.ApplicationInsights(new TelemetryConfiguration()
                {
                    InstrumentationKey = "abcde-1234",
                    TelemetryChannel = new ServerTelemetryChannel()
                },
                new MyCustomTraceTelemetryConverter())
                .CreateLogger();
            builder.Services.AddLogging(builder => builder.AddSerilog(loggerConfiguration));
            return builder;
        }
```

However, we have an entry in the configuration file to configure Serilog per the following item which is used in both asp.net core and function applications:

```
"Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.Console" ],
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "Console",
        "Args": {
          "theme": "Serilog.Sinks.SystemConsole.Themes.AnsiConsoleTheme::Code, Serilog.Sinks.Console",
          "outputTemplate": "[{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss} {Level:u3}] {Message:lj} <s:{SourceContext}>{NewLine}{Exception}",
          "restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Information"
        }
      }
    ],
    "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext" ],
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Error",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Error",
        "System": "Error"
      }
    }
  }
```

To wire up `UseLogger()` extension in the asp.net core application I do this:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
            => CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host
                .CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder
                    .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context,config) =>
                    {
                        config
                            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{context.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
                    })
                    .UseStartup<Startup>()
                    .UseLogger();
                })
                .UseDefaultServiceProvider((context,options) =>
                {
                    options.ValidateScopes = context.HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment();
                    options.ValidateOnBuild = false;
                });
```

Also, to wire up `UseLogger(...)` in the function v3 application, I do this:

```
[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(ConnectionTracker.Startup))]
namespace ConnectionTracker
{
    public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddFunctionConfiguration("appsettings.json");
            builder
                .UseLogger(configuration)
                .Services
                .AddMyServices();
        }
    }
```

The problem that I am facing is that I'd like to log "Error and above" messages only without seeing Warnings and Information in Application Insights but it's not happening. What is being missing or done wrong in this configuration? Please note that nothing in terms of changing log levels is happening in MyCustomTraceTelemetryConverter class.

Comment: Are you using .net core? which version of .net core?

Comment: And where did you put the code `var loggerConfiguration = new LoggerConfiguration() xxx`? And did you use the `Log` method to log messages to app insights? I did a quick test in .net core mvc project, it was ok and only sent error messages.

Comment: @IvanYang Thanks for the reply. I am using asp.net core 3.1 and Azure Functions v3. I did not use `Log` method to log messages. I updated the original question by including further details in it. Please feel free to review the details that I reflected there.

Comment: @IvanYang any ideas on my updated question? Thanks.